# asp.net mvc linq sql distinct statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

i want use distinct statement for this query ;

```
 @{var VideoDersler = from vd in context.VideoDersler 
                      where (vd.Sinif==snfkurs) select new
                      {vd.Ders,vd.Sinif}; 
                       var distinct =VideoDersler.Distinct();
                      }
 @foreach (var vidyo in VideoDersler)
  {
  <tr>
  <td><a href="/url"> @vidyo.Ders</a></td>
  </tr>
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surround the linq in parentheses then you can use Distinct.

```
@{var VideoDersler = (from vd in context.VideoDersler where (vd.Sinif==snfkurs) select new
                                                {vd.Ders,vd.Sinif}).Distinct();  }
```

However this is bad practice to be doing this on your view. You should be filtering the data at the controller level and passing it in as a view model.